# React Plus Django: Can't update the django backend while creating a new Todo item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, frontend, backend

I created a Django + React Todo App which is working as expected on the frontend but the functionality of updating the backend when a new item/todo is not know to me well. Also, i was able to manage the delete functionality but not the rest (got stuck with handleItem function). Need help to make the add items functionality work :(

Frontend Code below, Backend code is here "https://bitbucket.org/Yash-Marmat/backend/src/master/"

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
//import "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      newID: 11,
      edit: false,
      cloneID: 0,
      cloneTitle: "",
      todoData: [], // will come from django backend
    };
    this.handleUserInput = this.handleUserInput.bind(this);
    this.handleAddItem = this.handleAddItem.bind(this);
    this.handleEdits = this.handleEdits.bind(this);
    this.renderEdits = this.renderEdits.bind(this);
    this.handleUpdates = this.handleUpdates.bind(this);
    this.onRemove = this.onRemove.bind(this);
    this.handleStrike = this.handleStrike.bind(this);
    this.refreshList = this.refreshList.bind(this);
    this.getTodos = this.getTodos.bind(this);
    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
  }

  // increment id
  increment() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      newID: prevState.newID + 1,
    }));
  }

  // Todo Creation Function (part 1)
  handleUserInput(event) {
    this.setState({
      userInput: event.target.value,
    });
  }

 // PROBLEM BELOW

// Todo Creation Function (part 2)
  handleAddItem(id) {
    const someID = this.state.newID;
    //console.log(someID)
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      todoData: [
        ...prevState.todoData,
        { id: someID, task: this.state.userInput },
      ],
      userInput: "", // im telling react to empty my userInput (the input box)
    }));
  }

  // Todo edit funciton (part 1)
  // function 1 (runs the very first time (if edit gets clicked))
  handleEdits(theId, theTitle) {
    this.setState({
      edit: true,
      cloneID: theId,
      cloneTitle: theTitle,
    });
  }

  // Todo edit function (part 2)
  // function 2  (runs automatically after function 1)
  // (will run only when the edit condition is true (when we click on edit button))
  renderEdits() {
    if (this.state.edit) {
      return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleUpdates}>
            <input
              autoFocus={true}
              placeholder="Update Todos"
              type="text"
              name="data"
              defaultValue={this.state.cloneTitle} // from the cloneTitle
              className="form-control"
            />
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="btn btn-sm btn-success ml-2 updateButton"
            >
              Update
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  // Todo edit Function (part 3)
  // function 3 (will run when function 2 runs)
  handleUpdates(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      todoData: this.state.todoData.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === this.state.cloneID) {
          item["task"] = event.target.data.value;
          return item;
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      }),
    });

    this.setState({
      edit: false,
    });
  }

  // Todo delete function
  //  onRemove(myId) {
  //    this.setState((prevState) => {
  //      const updatedList = prevState.todoData.filter((each) => each.id !== myId);
  //      return {
  //        todoData: updatedList
  //      };
  //    });
  //  }

  onRemove(myId) {
    axios
      .delete(`http://localhost:8000/api/todos/${myId}`)
      .then((res) => this.refreshList());
  }

  refreshList = () => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8000/api/todos/")
      .then((res) => this.setState({ todoData: res.data }))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  handleStrike(theId, theTask) {
    const todoData = this.state.todoData.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === theId) {
        item["id"] = theId;
        item["task"] = theTask;
        item["completed"] = !item.completed;
        return item;
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      todoData: todoData,
    });
  }

  // Lifecycle Method
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTodos(); // managing the django apis
  }

  // working with componentDidMount Method
  getTodos() {
    axios
      .get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todos")
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ todoData: res.data });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.todoData)
    return (
      <div className="card mb-3 sizing mx-auto">
        {this.renderEdits()}
        {this.state.todoData.map((item) => (
          <div className="card-body border text-grey" key={item.id}>
            <span className={"crossed-line" + (item.completed ? "" : "active")}>
              {item.task}
            </span>
            {/* edit button below */}
            <span
              onClick={() => this.handleEdits(item.id, item.task)}
              className="shift2 mr-1"
            >
              <i className="fas fa-edit"></i>
            </span>
            {/* delete button */}
            <span onClick={() => this.onRemove(item.id)} className="mr-2">
              <i className="shift fas fa-trash ml-20"></i>
            </span>
            <span
              className="shift3"
              onClick={() => this.handleStrike(item.id, item.task)}
            >
              {item.completed ? (
                <i className="fas fa-undo-alt"></i>
              ) : (
                <i className="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
              )}
            </span>
          </div>
        ))}
        <br />
        <span>
          <input
            autoFocus={true}
            placeholder="Add Todos"
            value={this.state.userInput || ""}
            onChange={this.handleUserInput}
            className="form-control"
          />
          <span
            style={{ color: "purple" }}
            className="addButton"
            onClick={() => {
              this.handleAddItem();
              this.increment();
            }}
            disabled={!this.state.userInput}
          >
            <i className="fas fa-plus-square shift ml-20"></i>
          </span>
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```